# Write formula in html

Tags: html, formula

How to write formula in html page?
For example I need to write square root of x power 2 minus y. I know only one way, LaTex. But I need easier way. I'm writing quiz testing system. Students should write answer, that contains formula. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which is used on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Combined with AsciiMath Input it seems to cover pretty much everything -> http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimathjax.html

Answer (score 1):

The only two answers I know of for that are using images:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/

...or using HTML math notation for that (although it is not that simple to use)
http://www.unics.uni-hannover.de/nhtcapri/mathematics.html

You also have this alternative, but it seems rather experimental...
http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/HTMLPlus/htmlplus_45.html
http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

Still, I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

[This is a utility](http://ans.hsh.no/home/mgg/gladtex/) to write math (using LaTeX syntax) in HTML, but you also need to have LaTeX installed on your machine to generate the images of the formulas.

Comment: Links is not available anymore. Please tell me the name of technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to render the answer, just make it is correct, then  the best way to go is probably to allow them to use something like `sqrt()`, `^` for power, etc..
I find this is the easiest way of writing if the input is for a machine.

You could just provide a small list of allowed functions with examples.
The bonus here would be that you can probably look around for a lib and use it to evaluate the answer.

So your example would be written like: `sqrt(x^2)-y`

Of course this can get very messy if you need to write complex equations but for the level you presented it should work fine.